# How to configure gitlab-runner workflow to run continuously two job of one project in two individual stages

Tags: workflow, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using Gitlab-runner 12.4.1.

I have a project using Gitlab-ci like:

```
stages:
- build
- deploy

build_a:
    stage: build

deploy_a:
    stage: deploy

build_b:
    stage: build

deploy_b:
    stage: deploy

build_c:
    stage: build

deploy_c:
    stage: deploy
```

I want to set my project workflow as `build_a > deploy_a > build_b > deploy_b > build_c > deploy_c`.

But it actually does as `build_a > build_b > build_c > deploy_a > deploy_b > deploy_c`.

How to configure `.gitlab-ci.yml` for the jobs work like my expectation?

Answer (score 0):

Like that:

```
stages:
    - build_a
    - deploy_a
    - build_b
    - deploy_b
    - build_c
    - deploy_c

build_a:
    stage: build_a

deploy_a:
    stage: deploy_a

build_b:
    stage: build_b

deploy_b:
    stage: deploy_b

build_c:
    stage: build_c

deploy_c:
    stage: deploy_c
```

Gitlab-CI will follow the order in "stages".
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages

Comment: Thanks but it isn't what I want.
According to your answer, the pipeline will be divided into 6 stages and 6 jobs arranged into 1 rows. But I want only 2 stages, all job will be arranged into 2 columns and 3 rows.

Comment: On your original question you requested:

"I want to set my project workflow as `build_a > deploy_a > build_b > deploy_b > build_c > deploy_c`"

Comment: I just mean that is the order of jobs but all build jobs should be in build stage and so should all deploy jobs.